# selecting most recent record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How to select most recent records if the records are having almost same kind of data...

example:

```
col1       col2          col3              col4
--------------------------------------------------
123         abc          1.1               12345
123         abc          1.1               123445
1234        dsv          2.0               123
1234        dsv          2.0               1233
12345       dsvw         1.2               1234
```

The maximum of `col4` when it compares with rest of the columns.

See the row1 and row2 data looks similar but we need the latest data based on col4.

Same thing with row3 and row4, data looks similar but we need the latest data based on col4.

And the required output is:

```
col1    col2   col3   col4
----------------------------
123     abc    1.1    123445
1234    dsv    2.0    1233
12345   dsvw   1.2    1234
```

Comment: What do you mean by `based on col4`?  Are you saying for the largest col4 value?  What would your desired output be if the second row had `abcd` for it's `col2` value?

Comment: Abe, I was wondering the same thing... the answer may deem the `GROUP BY` solutions inappropriate.

Comment: if the col2 is different value then the whole scenario is gonna be different and and I will have that col. The output will come under action when the all the rows are same except col4 value.

Comment: What do you mean by `The output will come under action`?  Can you just add another row to your example that includes a different col2 value and modify your desired output as needed so we can understand?

Comment: I am sorry for late reply. I will edit my question and i will add another row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
WITH example AS (
   SELECT t.*,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.col1
                                 ORDER BY t.col4 DESC) AS rnk
     FROM YOUR_TABLE t)
SELECT e.*
  FROM example e
 WHERE e.rnk = 1
```

..or:

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.col1
                                      ORDER BY t.col4 DESC) AS rnk
          FROM YOUR_TABLE t) e
 WHERE e.rnk = 1
```

The CTE doesn't provide any optimization over the derived table approach.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that "latest" means "largest"?

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    col1 INT, 
    col2 CHAR(3), 
    col3 DECIMAL(4,1), 
    col4 INT
);

INSERT @t SELECT 123, 'abc', 1.1, 12345
UNION SELECT 123, 'abc', 1.1, 123445
UNION SELECT 1234, 'dsv', 2.0, 123
UNION SELECT 1234, 'dsv', 2.0, 1233;

WITH t AS
(
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col4 DESC)
        FROM @t
)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
    FROM t
    WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: If you include DDL and sample data next time, maybe I'll win. :-)

Comment: What -- where's the `CREATE DATABASE` statement?!  If you look close enough, there's a kitchen sink in this answer =)

Comment: I'm trying to passively coerce people to include it in their questions, then I have less work to do trying to repro their issues. A tabular output or a screen shot of the results pane doesn't help me build sample data. :-)

Comment: IME, hit'n'miss.  Some appreciate the effort

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want:

```
select * from table t
where col4 = (select max(col4) from table where col1 = t.col1);
```

You may add other columns to the test as required (not clear from question if this is required), for example:

```
select * from table t
where col4 = (select max(col4) from table
              where col1 = t.col1 and col2 = t.col2 and col3 = t.col3);
```

Note: This will return multiple rows if there is are multiple records that share the same maximum value for col4. This may not be a problem, or you could use `DISTINCT` or some other treatment as required.

Comment: The potential issue with this is that `col4` values could be duplicated, so it wouldn't return distinct rows.  It'd be like using the DENSE_RANK function...

Answer (score -1):

I feel like i'm missing something because of all the other answers, but it seems to me this is a simple `MAX/group by`:

```
with temp as
(
select 123 as col1,'abc' as col2, '1.1' as col3, 12345 as col4
UNION
select 123, 'abc', '1.1'  ,123445
UNION
select 1234,'dsv','2.0' ,123
UNION
select 1234,'dsv' ,'2.0'  ,1233

)

SELECT col1, Col2, COl3, MAX(Col4)
FROM temp
GROUP BY col1, col2,col3
```

This would return your desired results

Comment: Nope. That won't return a single row for each col1 value - see expected results in question

Comment: I just ran the above query and it does.  Does it have to do with the sample data set that he gave?  I feel like I'm missing something here, but i'm not sure what...

Comment: What if col2 and col3 vary between rows with a given col1 - it isn't clear from the question (but it would near useless data if it didn't vary), in which case your query won't work.

Comment: I agree that it wouldn't work if that data varies.  I also, agree that it's not clear from the question.  I can't say that this isn't what he wants until I get clarification.

Comment: The line `The maximum of col4 when it compares with rest of the columns.` while unclear also makes me think that this might be what he is looking for.